# Syntax error in function with DATE_ADD and INTERVAL

Tags: mysql, function, date

Given this function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS expiration_date;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION expiration_date(lic_class VARCHAR(2), born_on DATE, at DATE) RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
    DECLARE age INTEGER;
    DECLARE span INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    SET age = YEAR(at) - YEAR(born_on);
    IF     age < 50                 THEN SET span = 10;
    ELSEIF age >= 50 AND age < 70   THEN SET span = 5;
    ELSEIF age >= 70 AND age < 80   THEN SET span = 3;
    ELSEIF age >= 80                THEN SET span = 2;
    END IF;

    DECLARE ret DATE;
    SET ret = DATE_ADD(at, INTERVAL span YEAR); 
    RETURN ret;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

it gives me:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE ret DATE;
>       SET ret = DATE_ADD(at, INTERVAL span YEAR); 
>       RETURN' at line 12

Why is that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [to the `DECLARE` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html)

> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Therefore, it is invalid to place the `DECLARE ret DATE;` after the `IF...ELSE` block.  Move it to the top with the other `DECLARE` declarations.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS expiration_date;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION expiration_date(lic_class VARCHAR(2), born_on DATE, at DATE) RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
    DECLARE age INTEGER;
    DECLARE span INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    -- No reason not to DECLARE up here!
    DECLARE ret DATE;

    SET age = YEAR(at) - YEAR(born_on);
    IF     age < 50                 THEN SET span = 10;
    ELSEIF age >= 50 AND age < 70   THEN SET span = 5;
    ELSEIF age >= 70 AND age < 80   THEN SET span = 3;
    ELSEIF age >= 80                THEN SET span = 2;
    END IF;

    SET ret = DATE_ADD(at, INTERVAL span YEAR); 
    RETURN ret;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```